# GPU available but not used

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10
- TensorFlow installed from: conda install tensorflow-gpu
- TensorFlow version: 2.1
- Python version: 3.7
- CUDA/cuDNN version: Cuda 10.1.105 / cudNN v7.6.5.32

When I run:
`print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())` and
`print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())`
on a Python terminal from Conda it says `True` for both of them. Same if I check it while running on VS Code. But when I run `nvidia-smi` there is no process on GPU.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFYoy.png)

[GPU-Z info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ0jI.gif)

Comment: can you share the screen after running nvidia-smi while you have a python program using the gpu running?

Comment: it is on the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU GT 720M have `Compute Capability (2.x)` therefore not supported by `cuda 10`. You can check Compute Capability tiers [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). You can also check CudNN support matrix [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-support-matrix/index.html). It is also mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) that at least you need Compute Capability 3.5. You could run on CC 3.0 GPU's but only on earlier versions of tensorflow-gpu/Cuda/CUdNN trio. So it seems that you need to upgrade or better use Colab for a while.

Comment: ```I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1416 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 720M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)``` Do you know why does it say "compute capability: 3.5" there?

Comment: Can you verify your GPU from device manager. And also can you verify if it has 64-bit memory interface or 128 bit. You may use GPU-Z for that. GT 720 is CC 3.5 but GT 720M is CC 2.1.

Comment: It is GPU 720M, I checked if is was compatible with CUDA before doing the whole process, and it is but I didn't realise that it is not with Tensoflow. Anyways I still don't undestand what it is that 3.5 that is said on my last comment.

Comment: Sure, It is compatible with cuda but the version may not match the needs. There could be two 720M's deployed by Nvidia. One is 64 bit and the latter is 128 bit. Thats why I'm asking you to check your GPU details via GPU-Z instead of task manager or etc. A name 720M doesn't helps us really. If it is 64-bit then its clearly CC 2.1, else it could be CC 3.5 and we should look somewhere else about the problem.

Comment: ok, i have just added to the description the screenshot with the GPU-Z info